# Reference for work including a tongue-in-cheek list of books whose titles included a world whose name sounded like "Skryblyz"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have a memory of some work (article, book, short story, review, etc.) connected with science fiction and fantasy which included a parodic list of book titles which included the name of a fictional world which, I think, sounded like "Skryblyz". I am pretty sure that at the time when I read this work, I had a strong feeling that the author wanted to make fun of Andre Norton's "Witch World" series (or possibly some other Andre Norton series).

I believe (but am not 100% sure) that the work itself was not named after these fictional books or their world, and quite possibly the fictional book series (which is the only thing which stuck in my memory) had little or no importance to the work itself.

I believe that I read this sometime between 1969-1985. Sorry not to be able to be more specific.

Can anyone help me to locate this work?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, please take a look at [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can recall any more details about the work which you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Just to be clear.  The work itself didn't have that name, it's the fictional works _within_ the world of the story you're looking for that used that name, correct?

Comment: @DavidW I believe (but am not 100% sure) that you are correct, the work itself was not named after these fictional books or their world, and quite possibly the fictional book series (which is what stuck in my memory) had little or no importance to the work itself.